# parsing string sent from ui into array in java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have an array comes from ui but i have used JSON.strignify() to send it, is there any way to parse  it to string?

my javascript function:

```
 function chooseChair() {
        var chairNum = [];
        $('.check:checked').each(function() {
            chairNum.push($(this).val());
        })
        var busId = $('.checkId').val();
        var chairNumber = JSON.stringify(chairNum);
        alert(chairNum);
        alert(busId);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/spr-data/searchChair",
            data : {
                chairNumber : chairNum,
                busId : busId
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
    }
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchChair", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
List<Chair> findChair(@RequestParam String chairNumber,
        @RequestParam Integer busId) {
    String[] chairNum = chairNumber.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < chairNum.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(chairNum[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("ChairNUMBER!!!!!!!!!" + chairNumber);
    return null;
}
```

and             System.out.println(chairNum[i]); gives this: ["3"
"6"
"9"] how can i remove brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better you just send your object into server to do this you should put your list in another Object( I use an inner class), also remember use RequestBody instead RequestParam

in the server side

```
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchChair", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody
        List<Chair> findChair(@RequestBody Reserv reserv) {
            List<String> chairNumber = reserv.getChairNumebers();
            int busId = reserv.getBusId();
            System.out.println("ChairNUMBER!!!!!!!!!" + chairNumber);
            List<Chair> chair = chairService.chairsFind(chairNumber, busId);
            System.out.println("HERE" + chair);
            return chair;
        }
    ...
      private class Reserv{
            int busId;
            List<String> chairNumber;
            //getter setters
        }
```

in the client side you should put your array in a new json object

```
 function chooseChair() {
            var chairNum = [];
            $('.check:checked').each(function() {
                chairNum.push($(this).val());
            })
            var busId = $('.checkId').val();
            var reserv = {
                           chairNumber: chairNum,
                           busId : busId
                         }
            alert(chairNum);
            alert(busId);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/spr-data/searchChair",
                data : reserv
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            })
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work the description is : description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.